# Multiple actions on the page - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table with many rows, and a user can perform many actions on each row. Data in the table are taken from the database. Each time an action is performed on a row, I need to get data from the database, create the table again, and do appropriate action. Is is a better way to handle this? I don't wan to use ajax here.

Comment: "I want to sail across the surface of the ocean in a proven vehicle for doing so, but I don't want to use a boat"

Answer (score 1):

You could cache the contents of the table, but I wouldn't, unless there's only a small amount of data.

Why don't you want to use Ajax? It's the most straightforward way to handle row-by-row operations while minimising the number of database operations.

If your concern is about the amount of development required, you might want to take a look at Telerik's [Extensions for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx), particularly the Grid control. The extensions are open-source (though Telerik will encourage you to take their paid-for option).